# How to use self defined variable in ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TableAll.*,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(vv.value), 0)
   FROM votes vv
   WHERE TableAll.id = vv.post_id
     AND TableAll.tc = vv.table_code) AS total_votes
FROM
  (SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 14 `rank`, 17 tc, id, word AS subject, '' name
   FROM loghatnameh_dehkhoda,
   (SELECT @rank1 := -13) q
   WHERE word like "test"

   UNION ALL

   SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 14 `rank`, 18 tc, id, word AS subject, TYPE name
   FROM loghatnameh_amid,
   (SELECT @rank2 := -12) q
   WHERE word like "test"

   ORDER BY rank
   LIMIT 0,
         11) TableAll;
```

It was working well on MySQL version 5.7.42, and after upgrading to MySQL version 8.0.34, it's getting broken and throwing:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 11
> ) TableAll LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: `rank` is reserved word in MySql 8.0 Use backticks.